# ASP.Net page methods execution time monitoring

Tags: asp.net, time, methods, execution

could anybody advice me, are there any approaches to calculate the methods execution time in asp.net page?

ASP.Net Trace doesn't suit me since it ignores ajax partial postbacks though just they are the tight place.

I have the page event which for some unknown reason executes slowly. Since the logic and event execution chain is rather complicated, I still unable to merely determine the culprit in debugger.

I'd like to measure the execution time of each method throughout the page, but I still see no way but insert redundant code lines (like timeBegin = DateTime.Now.... timeEnd=DateTime.Now = timeBegin etc) in the beginning and ending of each method. It seems to be ugly approach, does anybody know how to do it automatically? Are there tools which measure the methods execution time available?

Answer (score 1):

I am not 100% sure the below works in all cases. So far it does though. Note that **Context.Session.Item("CURRENT_WEB_USER")** is where I store the current user, and is therefore not readily available as part of the asp.net session variables.

The code hereunder is in replacement of **Global.aspx** that allows both full page timing and timing of developer code.

```
Sub Application_Start(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
End Sub

Sub Application_End(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
End Sub

Sub Application_Error(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
End Sub

Sub Session_Start(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
End Sub

Sub Session_End(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
End Sub

Sub Application_AcquireRequestState(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)
    If HttpContext.Current Is Nothing Then Return
    If HttpContext.Current.Session Is Nothing Then Return
    If TypeOf HttpContext.Current.CurrentHandler Is Page Then
        If Not Context.Items.Contains("Request_Start_Time") Then
            Dim MyPage As Page = HttpContext.Current.CurrentHandler
            AddHandler MyPage.Init, AddressOf PageInitEncountered
            AddHandler MyPage.Unload, AddressOf PageUnloadEncountered
            Context.Items.Add("Request_Start_Time", DateTime.Now)
            Dim User As String = Context.Session.Item("CURRENT_WEB_USER")
            Context.Items.Add("Request_User", User )
        End If
    End If

End Sub

Sub Application_ReleaseRequestState(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) 
    If HttpContext.Current Is Nothing Then Return
    If TypeOf Context.CurrentHandler Is Page Then
        Dim Page As Page = Context.CurrentHandler
        Dim StartDate As Date = Context.Items("Request_Start_Time") : If StartDate = Nothing Then Return
        Dim EndDate As Date = Now
        Dim StartProc As Date = Context.Items("Page_Init")
        Dim EndProc As Date = Context.Items("Page_Unload")
        Dim User As String = Context.Items("Request_User")
        LogEntry(StartDate, EndDate, StartProc, EndProc, User, Context.Request.Url.ToString)
    End If

End Sub

Public Sub PageInitEncountered(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)
    Context.Items.Add("Page_Init", DateTime.Now)
End Sub

Public Sub PageUnloadEncountered(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)
    Context.Items.Add("Page_Unload", DateTime.Now)
End Sub

Public Sub LogEntry(StartDate As Date, EndDate As Date, StartProc As Date, EndProc As Date, User As String, PageURL As String)
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(" (" & LogEntry.RequestMs & " - " & LogEntry.DurationMs & ") (" & User & ") " & PageURL)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This may not be what you are looking for, but [RedGate](http://www.red-gate.com/products/ants_profiler/index.htm) has a product called Performance Profiler that does exactly that.  They do have a 15 day trial so you can even download it and try it out on your current issue. IMHO, it's worth every penny.

Comment: thanks.
but 'profile method-level performance' menu item causes message box 'The target of the active project is not an executable file. Choose a project that builds an executable program, or set an external program in the project settings.

(the active project is my web application).
So I don't know how to make it work.

Comment: Well, depending on where you are trying to run the project (IIS or Visual Studio Web), you can select a different option for where to have the profiler tie into the running app.  I've been able to successfully debug both VS and IIS sites.  Check out the demo videos as they will step you through how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use asp.net performance counters and other things also. But that will not measure a page speed but they will measure a over all application performance.